Assembly x86 to C
As I understand it the following assembly x86 code converts to something like this in C:
cplayground.com
#include <stdio.h>

void f(const int *arr, int length) {
    char buffer[32] = {0};
    const char *table = "DCBAHGFELKJIPONMTSRQXWVUZY";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = table[arr[i]];
    }
    puts(buffer);
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {21, 7, 0, 16, 10, 12, 18};
    int length = 7;
    f(arr, length);
    return 0;
}

.text:00000627 ; ||||||||||||||| S U B R O U T I N E ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
.text:00000627
.text:00000627 ; Attributes: bp-based frame
.text:00000627
.text:00000627 public _Z1fPhj
.text:00000627 _Z1fPhj proc near ; CODE XREF: main+53 p
.text:00000627
.text:00000627 var_5C = dword ptr -5Ch
.text:00000627 var_50 = dword ptr -50h
.text:00000627 var_4C = dword ptr -4Ch
.text:00000627 var_47 = dword ptr -47h
.text:00000627 var_43 = dword ptr -43h
.text:00000627 var_3F = dword ptr -3Fh
.text:00000627 var_3B = dword ptr -3Bh
.text:00000627 var_37 = dword ptr -37h
.text:00000627 var_33 = dword ptr -33h
.text:00000627 var_2F = word ptr -2Fh
.text:00000627 var_2D = byte ptr -2Dh
.text:00000627 var_2C = byte ptr -2Ch
.text:00000627 var_C = dword ptr -0Ch
.text:00000627 var_4 = dword ptr -4
.text:00000627 arg_0 = dword ptr 8
.text:00000627 arg_4 = dword ptr 0Ch
.text:00000627
.text:00000627 push ebp
.text:00000628 mov ebp, esp
.text:0000062A push ebx
.text:0000062B sub esp, 64h
.text:0000062E call __x86_get_pc_thunk_bx
.text:00000633 add ebx, 199Dh
.text:00000639 mov eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:0000063C mov [ebp+var_5C], eax
.text:0000063F mov eax, large gs:14h
.text:00000645 mov [ebp+var_C], eax
.text:00000648 xor eax, eax
.text:0000064A mov [ebp+var_47], 'DCBA'
.text:00000651 mov [ebp+var_43], 'HGFE'
.text:00000658 mov [ebp+var_3F], 'LKJI'
.text:0000065F mov [ebp+var_3B], 'PONM'
.text:00000666 mov [ebp+var_37], 'TSRQ'
.text:0000066D mov [ebp+var_33], 'XWVU'
.text:00000674 mov [ebp+var_2F], 'ZY'
.text:0000067A mov [ebp+var_2D], 0
.text:0000067E sub esp, 4
.text:00000681 push 20h ; size_t
.text:00000683 push 0 ; int
.text:00000685 lea eax, [ebp+var_2C]
.text:00000688 push eax ; void *
.text:00000689 call _memset
.text:0000068E add esp, 10h
.text:00000691 mov [ebp+var_50], 0
.text:00000698
.text:00000698 loc_698: ; CODE XREF: _Z1fPhj+A5¯j
.text:00000698 mov eax, [ebp+var_50]
.text:0000069B cmp [ebp+arg_4], eax
.text:0000069E jbe short loc_6CE
.text:000006A0 mov edx, [ebp+var_50]
.text:000006A3 mov eax, [ebp+var_5C]
.text:000006A6 add eax, edx
.text:000006A8 movzx eax, byte ptr [eax]
.text:000006AB movzx eax, al
.text:000006AE mov [ebp+var_4C], eax
.text:000006B1 mov edx, [ebp+var_4C]
.text:000006B4 mov eax, [ebp+var_50]
.text:000006B7 add eax, edx
.text:000006B9 movzx eax, byte ptr [ebp+eax+var_47]
.text:000006BE lea ecx, [ebp+var_2C]
.text:000006C1 mov edx, [ebp+var_50]
.text:000006C4 add edx, ecx
.text:000006C6 mov [edx], al
.text:000006C8 add [ebp+var_50], 1
.text:000006CC jmp short loc_698
.text:000006CE ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:000006CE
.text:000006CE loc_6CE: ; CODE XREF: _Z1fPhj+77 j
.text:000006CE sub esp, 0Ch
.text:000006D1 lea eax, [ebp+var_2C]
.text:000006D4 push eax ; char *
.text:000006D5 call _puts
.text:000006DA add esp, 10h
.text:000006DD mov eax, 0
.text:000006E2 mov ecx, [ebp+var_C]
.text:000006E5 xor ecx, large gs:14h
.text:000006EC jz short loc_6F3
.text:000006EE call __stack_chk_fail_local
.text:000006F3
.text:000006F3 loc_6F3: ; CODE XREF: _Z1fPhj+C5 j
.text:000006F3 mov ebx, [ebp+var_4]
.text:000006F6 leave
.text:000006F7 retn
.text:000006F7 _Z1fPhj endp

The C code is supposed to result in a real English word. However, it results in "WEDTJPR", which is not a real word. No matter how I twist it I can't get anything close to resembling a real word.
What am I missing?
Any help is appreciated!
EDIT:
This did the trick (cplayground.com):

Alphabet in the correct order: *table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
Add the i: buffer[i] = table[i + arr[i]];


The reverse string in e.g. mov [ebp+var_47], 'DCBA' is because of endianness.
Intel-based (and therefore AMD) systems are little endian, where the string ABCD will need to be stored as DCBA to get the correct locations in memory (A will be stored before B in memory, etc.).
Your translation misses that very important part. So the solution is simply to write the string of the alphabet in the correct order.

This actually depends on the dialect of assembly language that you're using. In NASM's input, syntax like mov dword [ebp+var_47], 'DCBA' (I inserted the needed size keyword) would actually write the same string to memory (DCBA) as you specified in the source, not the reverse. Not saying your answer is wrong, it just isn't true of all x86 assemblers.

x86 uses the same endianness for immediates in machine code as it does for data loads/stores, so mov [mem], imm32 copies 4 bytes unchanged from the machine code to the memory destination.  Presumably MASM syntax's insane and confusing behaviour of multi-character literals as word / dword constants not working that way is somehow inspired by x86 being little-endian, but as @ecm says, this is purely an asm-syntax effect.  Wouldn't be the only weird thing MASM does, e.g. mov eax, [123] is mov-immediate not a load, ignoring the brackets because there's no register inside them...
